# Show Splash screen until application load in android using phonegap

Tags: cordova

I want to show a background image until the application loads in Android, in the first time I make a download from webservice, so it takes around 10 sec. But I will save this data on database so next time, when application relaunch,  I want to show the image only for 2 sec. How do I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: No sir i want to show splash screen till application load , 2 sec is example.actually to get data from web service it take around 5 sec ,but second time it take less time than first to load .how to do that

Answer (score 4):

I think my blog post explains it pretty well:

http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.com/2012/04/phonegap-android-splashscreen-just-got.html

basically you set the timeout to a long value and then call navigator.splashscreen.hide() from the javascript side when you want it to go away.